# Open a specifc URL in Fluid.app

Tags: web-browser, url, fluid.app

I use [Fluid.app](http://fluidapp.com/) for particular websites, such as a bug tracker, or a Wiki. However, when I receive notifications in an e-mail with that URL and click on it, I'll get the page opened in the default browser.

Is there a way to open a website in the Fluid.app instead?

P.S.: I have looked at RCDefaultApp, but could not find a way to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem and wrote a little AppleScript to handle this. You can find the app here: https://github.com/biafra23/Default-Fluids

You need to make this script your default browser. 
This can be achieved with Safari: 
Menu -> Safari -> Preferences -> General -> Default web browser

The source is in https://github.com/biafra23/Default-Fluids/blob/master/default_browser.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/main.scpt

It contains sections like this:

```
if this_URL contains "facebook.com" then
  tell application "/Applications/Fluids/facebook.app"
    activate
    open location this_URL
  end tell
else if 
...
else
  -- default browser here
  tell application "/Applications/Firefox.app"
  activate
    open location this_URL
  end tell
end if
```

You need to make changes to those according to your setup with the AppleScript Editor.

It is not as convenient as choosyosx but its free.

Comment: Danke Dirk, for sharing!. This works great and is just what I needed.

Comment: I found put today that VLC 2.0.2 can open youtube urls (as long they are not https). You can have vlc open youtube.com/watch urls.

Comment: Small warning here - this script will break the default OS opening of .html files or any link that starts with `file:///`.  Dropbox contextual menu functionality and other things that rely on local links may break as a result.

Answer (score 8):

Developer of Fluid here. The only way I know of to do this is with an additional utility like [Choosy](http://www.choosyosx.com/) or [Browser Fairy](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/browser-fairy/id483014855?mt=12) (app store link).

Comment: +1 for Choosy. I use it to direct links to Facebook, Jira, Google Reader and more to Fluid apps. Choosy lets you create rules for URLs that get passed to the selected Fluid instance. You can also select a default browser for links that don't match a rule, or have it pop up a list of browsers for you to choose from.

Comment: It's been almost three years since this came up, and Choosy no longer seems to be supported by its developer.

Comment: @jer-el: [Browser Fairy](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/browser-fairy/id483014855?mt=12) (App Store link) is not free, but seems to do the job (and was last updated in March 2015).